Did Alexander McCall Smith make up the "African proverb" "talking about pumpkins doesn't make them grow"?
A recent LinkedIn post presented the following sentence as an "African proverb":

Talking about pumpkins doesn't make them grow.

I object to the idea of presenting something as an "African proverb", as if Africa were some amorphous entity and not the culturally most diverse continent on the planet, but that's not really the point of this question. When looking for the source of this sentence, I could only find attributions to Alexander McCall Smith, more particularly his novel The No. 1 Ladies' Detective Agency.
There are numerous lists of "African proverbs" on the web, but none of those I searched contain the above "proverb". For example:

Louisa Davis: 200+ Best African Proverbs And Wise Sayings, Mindjournal, December 2021.
African Proverbs: Wisdom Passed Down Through Generations, Africa Rebirth, 20 July 2023.
Zimbabwean Proverbs.
Barbara Brown: Some Botswana Proverbs, African Studies Center, Boston University.
Top 69 Zimbabwean Proverbs and Sayings 2024 Updates You Must Know. Wisdom from Zimbabwe, Proverbs Hub.
Les proverbes africains, La Liste (no date).
205 proverbes africains en 23 catégories, evolution-101.com.
Austin Jacks: Dictionnaire des plus beaux proverbes africains, Poèmes & Poésies, 5 August 2017.

I have included proverbs from Zimbabwe, because Alexander McCall Smith was raised in Southern Rhodesia (now Zimbabwe) and proverbs from Botswana, because that is where his The No. 1 Ladies' Detective Agency series is set.
If Alexander McCall Smith didn't make up the proverb, is it possible to discover the culture or language from which it originates?

Update: the "proverb", if that is what it is, can be found in the novel The No. 1 Ladies' Detective Agency, which is the first one in the series named after it (emphasis mine):

‘But these are big issues,’ [Dr Maketsi] said jovially. ‘Talking about pumpkins doesn't make them grow.’ His mother-in-law said this frequently, and although he disagreed with almost everything she said, he found himself echoing her words only too often.

The above passage does not present the sentence as a proverb; rather than a traditional saying, it is something one specific person used to say. This makes it plausible that is not a real proverb.

If you search for that quote and exclude the word "smith" you get almost no results back. Which strongly suggests Smith made the quote up.

@MattThrower That is plausible, but since McCall Smith was raised in Southern Rhodesia, I can't exclude the possibility that he learnt a few proverbs in one of the languages spoken there (Zimbabwe has 16 official languages) that has never been translated into English.

"Never" is a strong word in the age of the internet. But I guess it is possible.

https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2016/07/30/487925796/it-takes-a-village-to-determine-the-origins-of-an-african-proverb

https://www.comboni.org.uk/files/African-Proverbs.pdf

It is unlikely that there is some such Proverb. It is more likely that the writer adapted something else or totally made that up to "suit" the narrative there. Hence the writer is intentionally vague about "Africa" rather than something like "Mauritania" , "Zimbabwe" , "Zulu" , "Masai" which will easily make it more interesting , at least more factual.

@Prem The person using that sentence on LinkedIn isn't Alexander McCall Smith, and Alexander McCall Smith doesn't present it as an "African proverb".

I think it is more like "Chinese Whispers" , amplified by Internet. The linkedin reference is made up , given the novel. The writer would have mentioned it like a Proverb or truism , in case that was so. When the writer did not do so , then it is unlikely that some random linkedin reference based on that is more truer or more factual.

pumpkins don't grow natively in Africa at all. It's a New World squash cultivated by Amerindians. So a saying like that puts Dr. Maketsi among an elite of educated people as it refers to a non-African vegetable from the New World. I assume he got it from his mother-in-law for that reason. We, in Western countries, often cite aphorisms etc, that come from Asia or elsewhere. Why shouldn't an African doctor, the character Dr. Maketsi, use a saying that would not be African? Even it made-up? It's actually quite funny. The linkedin person did not do her research properly.

Writers invent things. Why shouldn't they? If a writer claims something is a saying and it isn't, who cares? The point is does it work in the writing at hand... And it is not the character or author that says it's African. Right?

@Lambie: Tomatoes don't grow natively in Italy, or capsicum peppers in India, either; they're both New World plants. But I can't imagine Italian food without tomatoes or Indian food without hot peppers. Presumably the same might easily be true about pumpkins and Southern Africa.

@PeterShor Since the introduction of maize, pumpkins, cassava, potatoes, cabbages and other crops,people in Zimbabwe have changed their diet in such a way that only a few of the old traditional crops are currently used. This story could be repeated for almost every country in Africa. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/57a08ce240f0b64974001500/R7487l.pdf So I guess we'd have to ask the author or a Zimbabwean.

I emailed the publisher and have just received this email in response:

Dear [x],
I'm actually just off a call with Alexander and he says that he thinks he just invented that phrase.
All the best,
[Publisher]

Sometimes, just going direct to the source is useful.
